# Interpret folder path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to convert a file path in batch to powershell script. My file path in batch is

```
Xcopy %~d0\Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe" %userprofile%\downloads
```

and I tried below powershell script but not found.

```
Copy-Item -Path "${PSScriptRoot}\Softwares\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe" -Destination "$($env:USERPROFILE)\downloads"
```

I believe that I am using the wrong path abbrev in Powershell for %~d0 in batch. Please help me to correct it. Thanks.
(My powershell ps1 file is stored in a folder call Xray but the .exe file is stored in another folder called Softwares\Browsers. Both Xray and Softwares folders are in USB drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%~dp0` is used to get the full path of the script location.

`%~d0` is used to get the root drive letter of the script location.

The equivalent in powershell are :

- `${PSScriptRoot}` for the full path (`%~dp0`)
- `$(${PSScriptRoot}.Split("\")[0])` for the drive letter (`%~d0`)

### Example

##### Batch:

```
echo "%~dp0Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
echo "%~d0\Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
```

Output

```
"c:\full\path\of\the\Script\Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
"c:\Software\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
```

##### Powershell

```
Write-Host "$(${PSScriptRoot})\Softwares\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
Write-Host "$(${PSScriptRoot}.Split("\")[0])\Softwares\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe"
```

Output

```
C:\full\path\of\the\script\Softwares\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe
C:\Softwares\Browsers\ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.